# Regarding an outcome of an java class

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

I was developing the below class and when I execute the below class I get the following result..

```
public class Confusing {    
    private Confusing(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private Confusing(double[] dArray) {
        System.out.println("double array");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Confusing(null);
        // new Confusing((Object)null);
    }
}
```

Output :-

```
double array
```

could you please explain why the outcome is of double array on console.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Confusing(null)
```

method call goes to the most specific method

and here its

```
private Confusing(double[] dArray)
```

as `double[]` reference is more specific than generic`Object` reference

Answer (score 1):

> The most specific applicable overload is used.

In this case the most specific is double array thus you get "double array" as output